# UI Updates getting slower and slower in CollectionView

Tags: maui

I have a CollectionView in my .NET MAUI App which has an ObservableRangeCollection bound to it.

The ObservableRangeCollection is not changed in Code actively as by design don't want to do this. Instead there is a list which is then added and Values are added

```cs
...
var selectedStudentItems = GroupedStudentItems
    .SelectMany(groupedStudentSelectionItem => groupedStudentSelectionItem)
    .Where(StudentSelectionItem => StudentSelectionItem != null && StudentSelectionItem.IsSelected == true)
    .OrderBy(StudentSelectionItem => StudentSelectionItem.SortOrderIndex == -1 ? int.MaxValue : StudentSelectionItem.SortOrderIndex)
    .ToList();

SetSortOrderIndexBasedOnSelectedStudentItemsOrder(selectedStudentItems);

MinMaxEntryPairs.Clear();

SelectedStudentItems.Clear();
SelectedStudentItems.AddRange(selectedStudentItems);

OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedStudentItems));
...
```

I also detected that my Memory Consumption detected via following snippet goes up from time to time. Don't know if async Code can have an impact on it, but I just have variables in these methods that are scoped in the method itself.

```cs
long memoryUsage = GC.GetTotalMemory(false) / (1024 * 1024)
```

**SelectedStudentItems** is the ObservableRangeCollection and here I am actively clearing the Bound List and add the range of the selected Student item objects.

What I can see in Emulator is that the Updates of the UI are getting slower and slower from after a while.

In the Release Version of my App on the iPhone the App is just closed without a message.

So, I am still looking for clues if the updates of the ObservableRangeCollection could be a problem and I should not do it or change to a different Thread and do it or explicitly do it on the MainThread.

==== **Update**: Showing why I need a new ObservableRangeCollection ====

```cs
'Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Invalid update: invalid number of sections. The number of sections contained in the collection view after the update (2) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the collection view before the update (2), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (1 inserted, 0 deleted). Collection view: <UICollectionView: 0x7fd1e2040200; frame = (0 0; 384 408); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600003718930>; backgroundColor = UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 0 0; layer = <CALayer: 0x600007f4f440>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {384, 207}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}; layout: <Microsoft_Maui_Controls_Handlers_Items_ListViewLayout: 0x7fd1dafdbd40>; dataSource: <Microsoft_Maui_Controls_Handlers_Items_ReorderableItemsViewController_1: 0x7fd1dc229d30>>
Native stack trace:
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8004288ab __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007ff80004dba3 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   Foundation                          0x00007ff800b870cc _userInfoForFileAndLine + 0
    3   UIKitCore                           0x000000010cc935a5 -[UICollectionView _endItemAnimationsWithInvalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:animator:collectionViewAnimator:] + 13198
    4   UIKitCore                           0x000000010cc8edab -[UICollectionView _updateSections:updateAction:] + 402
    5   UIKitCore                           0x000000010cc8ee77 -[UICollectionView insertSections:] + 64
    6   libxamarin-dotnet-debug.dylib       0x0000000108d2a149 xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSend + 217
    7   ???                                 0x0000000109298ca7 0x0 + 4448685223
    8   libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x00000001099793da ves_pinvoke_method + 474
    9   libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x000000010996b655 interp_exec_method + 3717
    10  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x0000000109968e03 interp_runtime_invoke + 259
    11  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x000000010978e0b8 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 136
    12  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x0000000109796ada mono_runtime_try_invoke_span + 1818
    13  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x000000010974d4ec ves_icall_InternalInvoke + 284
    14  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x0000000109758024 ves_icall_InternalInvoke_raw + 100
    15  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x000000010997a570 do_icall + 288
    16  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x00000001099790ea do_icall_wrapper + 346
    17  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x000000010996b4af interp_exec_method + 3295
    18  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x0000000109968e03 interp_runtime_invoke + 259
    19  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x000000010978e0b8 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 136
    20  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x0000000109796ada mono_runtime_try_invoke_span + 1818
    21  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x000000010974d4ec ves_icall_InternalInvoke + 284
    22  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x0000000109758024 ves_icall_InternalInvoke_raw + 100
    23  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x000000010997a570 do_icall + 288
    24  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x00000001099790ea do_icall_wrapper + 346
    25  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x000000010996b4af interp_exec_method + 3295
    26  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x0000000109968e03 interp_runtime_invoke + 259
    27  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x000000010978e0b8 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 136
    28  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x0000000109791d2e mono_runtime_invoke + 142
    29  libxamarin-dotnet-debug.dylib       0x0000000108d2150f xamarin_invoke_trampoline + 6335
    30  libxamarin-dotnet-debug.dylib       0x0000000108d28de9 xamarin_arch_trampoline + 105
    31  libxamarin-dotnet-debug.dylib       0x0000000108d29fca xamarin_x86_64_common_trampoline + 118
    32  UIKitCore                           0x000000010d17d3dd -[UIGestureRecognizer _componentsEnded:withEvent:] + 153
    33  UIKitCore                           0x000000010d82156d -[UITouchesEvent _sendEventToGestureRecognizer:] + 662
    34  UIKitCore                           0x000000010d16d61b -[UIGestureEnvironment _updateForEvent:window:] + 469
    35  UIKitCore                           0x000000010d7c443b -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 5282
    36  UIKitCore                           0x000000010d797cae -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 898
    37  UIKitCore                           0x000000010d840861 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 9381
    38  UIKitCore                           0x000000010d842f69 __processEventQueue + 8334
    39  UIKitCore                           0x000000010d8392a1 __eventFetcherSourceCallback + 272
    40  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff800387fe5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    41  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff800387f24 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 157
    42  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff800387721 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 212
    43  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff800381e23 __CFRunLoopRun + 927
    44  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8003816a7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560
    45  GraphicsServices                    0x00007ff809cb128a GSEventRunModal + 139
    46  UIKitCore                           0x000000010d776ad3 -[UIApplication _run] + 994
    47  UIKitCore                           0x000000010d77b9ef UIApplicationMain + 123
    48  libxamarin-dotnet-debug.dylib       0x0000000108ce464a xamarin_UIApplicationMain + 58
    49  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x000000010997a5a9 do_icall + 345
    50  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x00000001099790b3 do_icall_wrapper + 291
    51  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x000000010996b4af interp_exec_method + 3295
    52  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x0000000109968e03 interp_runtime_invoke + 259
    53  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x000000010978e0b8 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 136
    54  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x00000001097960cc do_exec_main_checked + 92
    55  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x00000001098c4cb2 mono_jit_exec + 354
    56  libxamarin-dotnet-debug.dylib       0x0000000108d28c77 xamarin_main + 1927
    57  MacroOptimizerApp                   0x0000000108630754 main + 68
    58  dyld                                0x00000001089c22bf start_sim + 10
    59  ???                                 0x000000011030e52e 0x0 + 4566607150
'
```

Comment: This is a known issue on the GitHub and you can check this thread about [Memory leak when CollectionView.ItemsSource changes](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14664). For now, it has not been resolved. You can follow it up.

Comment: It says when the ```ItemsSource``` is charged. Well, I posted just some part of the Code. There is another ```ObservableRangeCollection``` which is bound in another View and there, I had to replace the ```ObservableRangeCollection``` with a new instance (```new ObservableRangeCollection()``` as the combination of Clear() and AddRange() on the Property lead to a crash reproducible. So, I hat to use a new instance. Is this then already considered to be a new ```ItemsSource```?

Comment: Yes, it will be considered as a new ItemSource. You can see this issue has been put into the milestones [the  .NET 8 + Servicing, .NET 8 SR2](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/milestone/48). You can wait for the next version update to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for this information. Besides my original question, do you know for when the coming SRs are planned?

Comment: I do not know the time of the coming SRs. But you can follow this issue up and provide more information for the developers which can help the issue work out.

Comment: My problem why I needed a new Instance of the ```ObservableRangeCollection``` is shown in the Update of my question. When I call ```Clear()``` or when I remove all Items of the ```ObservableRangeCollection``` with ```RemoveAt(i)``` is the Exception that is called. So for me right now the only thing I could do was creating a new Instance of the ```ObservableRangeCollection``` which you mentioned could be the issue.